# How to prevent antiseo attack

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, seo

I have a website. A bot visiting everyday my website and leaving in 0 seconds. So makes 100% exits. I'm trying to prevent this because it decreaces my SEO ranking.

I face this bot with Asp.Net and Php.

So far, I have tried the following code in htaccess
but this does not work.

How can I prevent this antiseo attack and the bot that makes 100% exits?

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(ref=.*)?\ HTTP [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-as\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-us\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-eu\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*hulfingtonpost\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*apanews\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*adcash\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*aliexpress\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*bestwebsitesawards\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*buttons-for-website\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*bycontext\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*cenokos\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*cenoval\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*cityadspix\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*darodar\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*econom\.co [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*edakgfvwql\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*gobongo\.info [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.info [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.org [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*iskalko\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*jollygame\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*luxup\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*max-start\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*o-o-6-o-o\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*o-o-8-o-o\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*priceg\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*savetubevideo\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*screentoolkit\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*semalt\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*seoexperimenty\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*slftsdybbg\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*socialseet\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*superiends\.org [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*vodkoved\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*websites-reviews\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*websocial\.me [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ykecwqlixx\.ru [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*simpleshare-buttons\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.hqtunes.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```

web.config :

No code added

Comment: a) seo questions are generally off topic here (read the tag information) although the "how to achieve something in htaccess" side of the question is probably ok. b) are you sure it _actually_ affects your seo, given that Google etc has no way of knowing about this bot?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I can add screenshots of this attacks. The bot do this everyday. This is a known issue. There are so many bots like this.

Comment: @Machavity, my question is different.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar type of bot, except it's visiting all my pages and leaving. My site is very new with few visits per day so this is hurting my ranking quite a bit I think.

Comment: @AlexBanman Later on, I thougth, this visits are real users and Analytics couldn’t see the user info, becaouse of something. For example if the visitor comes from my Facebook post, its seen as 0 second. And here, your visits may not be bot and they may be search engine crawlers.

Comment: Thank you @tubefavorites.com, I didn't think it could be search engine crawlers. Do you know if there is anything I can do about this? - In regards to real visitors spending 0:00 time on your site, if they only visit one page it will count as 0 seconds on the website.

Comment: @Alex Banman You’re welcome. You can:
Keep sharing your site on social media
and if possible always share at the same time / day.
If you familiarize users with visiting your site, you may see longer visits.
Thus, the remaining 0 second visits will not catch your attention.